# How do I update mySQL with PHP, but only if the last update was more than 24hrs ago?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a table of different users, but I want to be able to limit how frequently the user can update their own information. In the table, the timestamp is automatically updated when the user makes a change.

The page automatically updates their information with `UPDATE edits SET EDITS=EDITS+1 WHERE ID='$sID'` when it loads, but I would like for that to be ignored if the last update was less than 24hrs ago.

I'm not sure if that can be solved in UPDATE, or if there is a better alternative.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your column for last update is `last_updated`

```
UPDATE edits SET EDITS=EDITS+1 WHERE ID='$sID' AND DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR)>last_updated
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add a column to the database containing the last update. Let's assume it's called last_update and `DATETIME` format.

`$one_day_ago = strtotime('24 hours ago');`

Then run this query:

`UPDATE edits SET EDITS=EDITS+1 WHERE ID='$sID' AND last_update <= FROM_UNIXTIME('$one_day_ago')`